# In Excel - How do I count multiple drop down items and quantities on multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vlookup, countif

I have an excel workbook with multiple worksheets with departments product sales data. The sheets have a column with drop down menu items to select a product. Right next to these products is the quantity sold.

How do I gather the total quantities sold per product?

I'm thinking it would use a combination of VLOOKUP and COUNTIF?

I don't have a screen shot but here's a pictorial example

```
Department 1
Employee 1 ---- Product-------Number of items sold
----------------sprocket1---------------3-------
----------------sprocket2---------------9-------
----------------widget 11---------------12------

What I want to achieve:
Total Department Sales
Sprocket 1 ----3
Sprocket 2 ----9
Sprocket 3 ----
...
Widget 1--------
....
Widget 11 -----12
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use SUMIF
Assuming your products are in column G, the quantities are in column H and the list of products you want to sum are starting from cell A1, you can write `=SUMIF(G:G,A1,H:H)` to cell B1 and pull down.
It will sum the quantities in column H if the value of column H equals to the values in column A.